# Losing the messages sent from publisher while consumers are spawning up in Rabbit mq

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm just exploring the rabbit mq topics https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-javascript.html

 When I'm running continuously `./receive_logs_topic.js "#"` (consumer) and publishing the message it works fine. 
 
But when I kill consumer and send the message via publisher 2-3 times and again launch the consumer then the it's not processing the message which i sent before. 
 I'm comparing with rabbit queues that whenever the consumer is back it will process the pending messages.

Is `topics` work in this fashion only or I'm messing with some configuration?

Comment: Try channel.queueDeclare(String queue, boolean durable) on publisher and use same queue name for binding the consumer.

Comment: This will help you to understand what is missing on your implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148381/rabbitmq-persistent-message-with-topic-exchange .

Answer (score 1):

When you stop the consumer, the queues and bindings that it had declared will be deleted since they are exclusive queues. Since there is nowhere for RabbitMQ to route the messages, they will be dropped.

To resolve this, you will have to change the code to use well-known queues that both the publisher and consumer declare (with bindings, of course). That way it doesn't matter which process is started.

Comment: what do you mean by well-known queues?

Comment: Queues with names that you give them, rather than the automatically-generated names that exclusive queues have.